# Contents overlaying the image while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I request you to first have a look at https://www.womentechmakers.com/ and scroll a bit.
The overlaying effect on the image as we scroll is what i want to do.
Can you please suggest the css/javascript to do this!
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow and congratulations on your first question. However, the quality of your question is very low. Please see this and add more details including your research- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, a pointer to your question - Try researching 'parallax effect '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `background-attachment:fixed` CSS property to achieve this. A very quick demonstration can be seen below:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600);
  background-attachment: fixed; /*This stops the image scrolling*/
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 100px);/*Only 100px of screen visible*/
  background: lightgray;/*Set a background*/
}
```

```html
<body>Some text that will scroll</body>
```