# CSS - positioning divs

Tags: html, css

I am using zurb foundation and I would like to make a web page that would have a structure and scroll effect like this [one](https://www.hba.no/). I have an html structured like this:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
 ...
</head>
<body>
  <div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
      <div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
        <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
        ...
        </div>

        <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
          <div id="app">

            <!-- should be below the screen height --> 
            <div id="drawer">
              <div id="magazine-detail">
                 ...
              </div>
              <div id="magazine-detail-carousel">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- the background image of the main-section -->
            <div id="bg">
            </div>


            <!-- should take up the screen on the page load and start going below drawer on scroll down, on the z-axis -->    
            <div id="main-section">

              <!-- sticky fixed top-bar -->
              <div id="top-bar">
                ...
              </div>

              <div id="header">
                ...
              </div>

              <div id="carousel">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Since I need a zoom in effect on the background picture I have setup div `#bg` like this:

```
#bg {
  background-image: url('/img/cover.png');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: zoom 10s;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: static;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% { transform:scale(1,1); }
  100% { transform:scale(1.1,1.1);}
}
```

Since I saw in the example web page, on inspect in chrome, that the main page content, which in my case will be `#drawer`, is pushed with `margin-top` down to the bottom of the screen, I tried with this:

```
#drawer {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

But that is obviously not good, since when I have it like that I can't see the content of the other divs that are above the `#drawer`, because the margin takes the space with its color. And the `margin-top = 100vh` doesn't work for one more reason, I can't use jQuery scrollTop, for the divs that are not visible.

As for the main section, which for me in this case is what the `#front-slider` is in the example page, it needs to be on top of the `#bg` div, so that the `#bg` divs background-image serves as the backround of the `main-section`. I had to make div `#bg` so that I could have zoomed in effect on the background image, without `main-section` being scaled as well, when the background image is being zoomed in.

And for the `top-bar` I just need to be at the top like a sticky top-bar all the time.

I am not sure how to position all that to get the same effect and structure of the page shown as an example, I have tried with every possible css positions but nothing worked.

**Updated**

I have managed to work it out by using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wQQEM/254/).

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Contents overlaying the image while scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836183/contents-overlaying-the-image-while-scrolling)

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your code and explain it through an example?

Comment: @jbutler483 I would like that kind of effect, from the solution that you suggested but with content on top of the background-image

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to solve a number of problems in one go. start with one problem, make a jsfiddle and try solving it on its own, in isolation. then, if you have issues with that, ask another SO question.

Comment: Well, I would like to mostly solve the last problem that was mentioned and that is to get that fiddle working, not sure why the same code copy pasted is not working?